# Почему куки не передаются в запросе?

Tags: javascript, cookie, axios

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть маршрут по которому я передаю куки с **refresh токеном** что бы получить новую пару **access и refresh** токенов.

Бекенд при аутентификации выдаёт мне **access и refresh** токен. Refresh токен это по сути куки файл который имеет флаг **HTTP Only** для предотвращения похищения токена.

Но почему когда я делаю запрос на *my.domain.com* **/refresh** запрос делаю с localhost в браузере не передаётся моя кука с **refresh токеном** Разве браузер не должен сам подставлять куки к запросу?

**Куки файл с refresh токеном:**

```
refresh_token=0fe3c1e1-d505-448b-891b-29f3ea616006; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:08:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
```

**Запрос на обновление токенов** (я использую axios)

```js
this.axios.post('/refresh',{
       fingerprint: 'fingerprint'
     }).then(response => {
       console.log('refresh response',response)
     })
```

Домен front-end отличается от домена back-end может ли быть проблема связана с этим? Спасибо большое за проявленное внимание! Буду благодарен любому замечанию

Comment: _я делаю запрос на my.domain.com /refresh_ - добавь с  какого домена ты делаешь запрос

Comment: пока разрабатываю делаю с localhost

Comment: то есть сейчас шлешь запрос с localhost на my.domain.com?

Comment: Посмотри про атрибут [SameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) при выставлении cookie

Comment: да он есть, спасибо большое! Я даже не приметил